# File upload without form submit and asynchronously using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

[Upload-Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs37s.jpg)
[Master Page JQuery Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLTDh.jpg)

I have a input file control in my asp.net mvc view page as below. I am trying to load file from view to controller without using form and  with the help of jQuery ajax.

I am not using any **Iframe / FORM** in the view page. The file data is not posting to Controller.

**System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count** - is always showing as zero.
and **$("#AttachmenteUploadFile").get(0).files** also showing 'undefined' after deploy into stage environment.
Is something i am doing wrong in my HTML/JQuery/C#.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table id="tableView" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;color:black">                   
                <%=LabelHelper.Label("lblFile", "Supplier", "File", Model.User.CultureCode)%>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left">
                <input type="file" id="AttachmenteUploadFile" />
                <input type="button" id="btnUploadSubmit" value="Attach Document" />
            </td>
        </tr>             
    </table>
</div>   
</asp:Content>
```

**Here is the JQuery button Onclick event.**

```
$("#btnUploadSubmit").click(function() {
    if (RequiredFieldValidate() != false) {     
    var fileData = new FormData();
    var files = $("#AttachmenteUploadFile").get(0).files;    
    if (FileSizeValidation(filesize) != false) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }        
    fileData.append('documentType', $('#ddlDocumentType').val());
    var AttachTypeCode = $('#ddlDocumentType').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getExactPath('/Upload/UploadDocument'),
        data: fileData,
        dataType: 'Json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(jsonData) {
            var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
            FillGrid(jsonobj);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Unable to upload the Document.");
        }});}}});});
```

**Controller ActionResult from JQuery call.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadDocument() 
{     
    List < string > mimeType = DocumentumUtil.getMimeTypes();
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {          
        docFullPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName;
       docFullName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys[0];
       int index = docFullName.LastIndexOf('.');
       docname = docFullName.Substring(0, docFullName.LastIndexOf('.'));
       docExt = docFullName.Substring(index + 1);  
    }  
} catch {
}
return Json(AttachmentDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

some one please help. i'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Client side the issue resolved, since the FormData is not working in IE (document Mode 7), i have changed to higher version. But still **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count** i am getting zero

Comment: Have u tried with the below answer

Comment: yes i tried. no luck. I am not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: Try @Amit Sakare answer.

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute in your form.
enctype="multipart/form-data"

and Make sure the input file Name is same as Parameter of Action Method or property of Class

Comment: you mean the controller action name and input file name should be same?

Answer (score 0):

Place `Name` Attribute in design.

```
<input type="file" id="AttachmenteUploadFile" name="FileUpload_"/>
```

and Check once.

Comment: i tried the same, it is not working. when i create new asp.net-mvc  project the i am able to get the file upload control information, i am using this in one of my existing asp.net mvc application. where this functionality is not working. Is something i am missing any JQuery references? I am using Master page, it is referring the jquery references. please see the attachment image

Comment: That is not related to the `JQuery` references I think.

Comment: when i start the work i referred "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" and "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" in view page, And it worked in local. But in stage the script getting failed. all the dev work is done and i am stuck here before move to prod.